# Unit testing Handler

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am ultimately trying to unit test a custom base adapter, but I am stuck at one point: I am unable to figure out how to get the UI thread to process the message I have just passed to it via `sendEmptyMessage(...)`.

In my Activity I have a "`addFoo(Foo foo)`" method that updates an array and then calls "`sendEmptyMessage(1)`", and I have a `handleMessage` method that calls the ListView's adapter to tell it the data has changed.

I've boiled the unit test down to, roughly:

```
public void testAddFoo() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  assertTrue(mActivity.addFoo(foo));
  assertTrue(mActivity.getHandler().hasMessages(1));
  assertFalse(mActivity.getHandler().hasMessages(1));
  assertTrue(mActivity.fooListNotEmpty());
}
```

Naturally it is failing on that `assertFalse()` (this is a contrived example, simplifying it as best as I can).

What call can I make in to mActivity or its handler or looper to get it to process all pending messages? I have tried some suggestions I've read about calling Looper.loop(), within the UI thread, but those are stabs in the dark and they failed.

FWIW, I'm pretty sure that the handleMessage code is correct because if I call it directly (inside `@UiThreadTest`) like so:

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testAddFoo() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  assertTrue(mActivity.addFoo(foo));
  Message msg = Message.obtain();
  msg.what = 1;
  mActivity.handleMessage(msg);
  assertTrue(mActivity.fooListNotEmpty());
}
```

the test ends up working as expected.

Comment: can you post your code that sets up the handler?

Comment: @sugarynygs: The handler is set up with "mHandler = new Handler();" inside the activity declared as "public class FooActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback". mHandler is made available to JUnit via "public Handler getHandler() { return mHandler; }"

Comment: am I correct in saying that you are explicitly creating a new `Handler` as well as implementing `Handler.Callback`?

Comment: @sugarynygs: That's right, I'm following the pattern laid out in the docs, implementing Handler.Callback and then, essentially, exposing the Handler within the class as a member. The problem I'm having is that I want to be able to test that the message was processed after sending it. Basically, I want to trigger the processing of the message between that assertTrue and assertFalse (which would then be verifying that the message was removed from the queue).

Comment: @dpk.  i am pretty sure that your are not exposing the `Handler` as you think by instantiating it that way when you are implementing it.  When you implement it in your activity, it becomes part of your class which is why your `Activity` will override `handleMessage`.  Please see the answer I posted at the same time as the comment.

Comment: @sugarynygs: I typo'd in my response, I am using "mHandler = new Handler(this);". Sorry about that. The JavaDoc for that constructor implies that I am then working with the queue for the activity's main thread. I saw your reply, and thanks for it, but it doesn't solve the problem of triggering or waiting for the handler to process the message.

Comment: @dpk. remove the implements `Handler.Callback` and create a default handler as explained in my answer.  i have that working in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing `Handler.Callback` in your activity then you should just do

```
assertTrue(mActivity.hasMessages(1));
```

otherwise do not implement the callback and use

```
mHandler = new Handler() {

// override Handler methods as required
// ie handleMessage(Message msg)

};
```

and

```
assertTrue(mActivity.mHandler.hasMessages(1));
```

Comment: You're right, I can easily test sending messages if I move from using the callback interface to a member handler. I'm not sure what voodoo is going on under the hood that allows the messages to actually be processed, but I guess, for now, I will just have to accept that "it happens". Thanks.

Comment: Your'e welcome.  Out of interest does assertTrue(mActivity.hasMessages(1)); not work when you implement the Handler.Callback?

Answer (score 2):

If your Activity implements Handler.Callback and you want messages to show up in your handleMessage method, then you need to pass in your Activity when you initialize the Handler in onCreate.

```
mHandler = new Handler(this);
```

I know you got the member Handler approach working, but I'm adding this for people like me who show up here trying to figure out how to get the Handler.Callback interface approach working.